# Does the .co.uk registry (Nominet) have a 60 day waiting period for domain transfer?

Tags: domains, domain-transfer, transfer

Do .co.uk domains have a 60 day waiting period to transfer a domain? Also, is there a waiting period for any domain for which we use IPS Tag for domain name transfers?

Comment: Do you mean after newly registered or  a change of details as with .com?

Comment: By "transfer" do you mean moving the hosting to a different registrar or transferring ownership of the domain to a new registrant?

Answer (score 3):

Nominet.uk (the **registry** behind `.co.uk`) do not have any explicit terms on transfers of `.co.uk` domains, unless the domain is "expired" or "suspended" (from 30 days after expiry, lasts for 60 days). Domains in these statuses would need to be renewed prior to them being transferred.

From the [.UK Registry-Registrar Agreement 26 May 2020](https://media.nominet.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/UK-Registry-Registrar-Agreement-26-05-2020.pdf), section B.1.15:

> You may not transfer a domain name during the expiry period, except as set out in paragraph E.3.6

However, some **registrars** do seem to enforce a 60 day limit on transfers, for example [GoDaddy's rules on transferring out](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/transfer-my-domain-away-from-godaddy-3560) state:

> You won't be able to transfer your domain away if it's within 60 days of registration or a previous transfer, if a 60-day lock was applied after updating domain contact information, or if your domain has Ownership Protection.

and:

> **Note** Option showing disabled? You can't transfer your domain if it's within 60 days of registration or a previous transfer, if a 60-day lock was applied after updating domain contact information, or if your domain has Ownership Protection.

[Fasthosts also state](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/559):

> You can transfer .co.uk, .uk, .org.uk, .ltd.uk, .me.uk and .plc.uk domain names away from Fasthosts, provided that the domain name has been registered for at least 60 days.

Which seems to imply that you can transfer a domain within 60 days of another transfer, but not from the initial registration.

However, other registrars, such as [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/transfer/) will follow the registry guidelines and allow for immediate transfers.

Comment: no, ICANN rules around transfer have nothing to do with UK since it is a ccTLD and hence not under ICANN Regulations. Also transfers in UK are completely different from transfers in gTLDs, as UK uses a "push" type of transfer where everyone else is doing "pull".

Comment: Sorry but this answer is incorrect. `.uk` domains are ccTLDs like Patrick mentioned, the rules are set by the country not by ICANN. And like Patrick said, `.uk` domains are a particularly wacky case when it comes to transfers.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've added two examples of registrars that do enforce a 60 day limit - so again, which part is wrong, and can you provide a better answer?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I've added two examples of registrars that do enforce a 60 day limit - so again, which part is wrong, and can you provide a better answer?

Comment: You are still just quoting ICANN requirements (the 60 days stuff). The fact that 2 registrars are **maybe** also enforcing it for other TLDs is irrelevant. It does not come from the registry. And what you quote from .UK registry has more to do with expiration than has to do with transfers  and does not say anything aobut a specific "waiting period".

Comment: And you can as well find registrars that do not enforce any kind of 60 days rule for transfer: https://www.gandi.net/en-US/domain/tld/uk, or https://www.namecheap.com/domains/transfer/ (click on "UK family", read "They can be transferred within 60 days after registration or a previous transfer")

Comment: You still seem to not want to accept the fact that 60 is not a magical number out of an hat, it was put in place by ICANN, for gTLDs. Then some ccTLDs and some registrars for all TLDs just decided to apply the same rules, but it is just their local policy. You will see a lot of documentation referencing that just because people are putting everything in the same bag and applying ICANN rules everywhere, which is in general an error. Hence you should not expect people to explicitely rebuke it but in contrary if nothing is writing there is no reason it would apply everywhere by default.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm not saying it's a magical number, and I agree that Nominet.uk don't require this limit - my original answer (albeit vaguely) stated that, and I've updated it to be more accurate. I still think it is valid to point out that some registries appear to be explicitly applying this (incorrectly) to their customers wishing to transfer out .co.uk domains as well (Fasthosts being the most obvious). WRT Ghandi.net they state a default position with a caveat to check to the specific rules, and then don't state a difference from those rules - which would you assume applies and why?

Comment: CcTLDs tend to have different rules than gTLDs, some are more or less aligned to gTLDs but not all of them, far from it. The problem is that some registrars (American registrars in particular) don't want to bother with the peculiarities of each extension or they ignore them. Thus they sometimes apply rules in a non-sensical way. What's worse is that some registrars don't handle transfers or renewals correctly and bad surprises can occur as a result (meaning: the registrant losing the domain name).